# diffrence between for loop and the generator expression

Tags: python, for-loop, generator-expression

I tried these two approaches to capitilize the first element of each word in string but i am unable to understand how the second approach is working.

```
s=input().split()

for i in s:
 
    print(' '.join(i.capitalize()))
```

this is the second approach

```
  a_string = input().split(' ')

  print(' '.join((word.capitalize() for word in a_string)))
```

output is

```
input-----mike hussey
```

output 1

```
M i k e

H u s s e y
```

output 2

```
Mike Hussey
```

Comment: There is no list comprehension in your code. There is a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions): perhaps that is what you mean?

Comment: @khelwood the second approach is a list comprehension. You are joining (looping through) the letters in the word at the first one, but the words in the second one.

Comment: @nagyl A generator expression is not a list comprehension.

Comment: @khelwood ok you're right. But its close enough to be seen as one.

Comment: @khelwood thanx i'll fix it

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/join-function-python/

Answer (score 0):

So you have a list of 2 words in the example.

```
s = ['mike', 'hussey']
```

In the first attempt, you are looping through the words, and joining the letters with spaces, capitalizing the first one. Also multiple `print` statements, so there will be multiple lines, as you could see.

```
print(' '.join(i.capitalize())) #i = ['m', 'i', 'k', 'e']
```

At the second attempt, you are joining the words, capitalizing the first letter of each word, no spacing between the letters. Also there are one `print` statement, so one line output only.

```
print(' '.join((word.capitalize() for word in a_string))) #a_string = ['mike', 'hussey']
```

---

#### Second approach:

First of all, you have the list above. First, you are capitalizing each word with

```
word.capitalize() for word in a_string
```

Now your list looks like `['Mike', 'Hussey']`. You are joining those words with spaces, so the output will be

```
Mike Hussey <-- space between the 2 capitalized words.
```

---

If you need spaces between the words, and new lines between the words, you should join the letter from each word with spaces, and join the words with new lines. Example:

```
print('\n'.join(' '.join(letter for letter in word) for word in a_string))
```

Comment: yeah  is it the syntax for generator expression  that first the for loop will run and then it perform the second step

Comment: What is your desired output? What should I explain? How the second one is working?

Comment: i think i have mistaken it as list comprehention that is why i am getting confuse . i will go with the syntax i guess that would help me btw thanx for your efforts man

Comment: Don't worry, its the same as the list comprehention, just used as a parameter for memory performance improvement. Its the same just goes under a different name. I added an explanation, and also an exaple to achieve the first output.